# How to add row value to the combobox

Tags: vb6

I have a table name 'product', and product_name, category as a fields. I want to add the product_name row value to the combobox where the category value is repeated....

```
 product_name | category
--------------+----------
 Ceiling fan  |  fan               
 Table fan    |  fan               
 Wall fan     |  fan
```

I try the following code but without do while statement it gives one value and when i am trying to loop it the machine hangs. Plz help

```
Option explicit
 Private sub cboCategories_Click()
  cboProducts.clear
  rs.open "select * from product". cn, adOpenDynamic. adLockOptimistic
   With rs
    .find "category=' " & cbiCategories.Text &  " ' "   
   .moveFirst
    With rs(0).value
    Do until rs.EOF
    cboProducts.AddItem rs(0).Value
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
   End with 
  End with
  End sub
```

This is my table at present.  I want to get the product_name field value to the combobox where the category name is the same, such as 'fan'

Comment: What combobox?  How are you retrieving this data from the table into your VB6 code at present?

Comment: I added two combo boxes combo1 and combo2 ...in combo1.list i added a category like fan, freeze, and so on .... now i want to add the value of product in combo2 where the combo1 value is = category value...

Comment: I am working on msaccess database ..

Comment: That's fine as further explanation, but doesn't help me help you at this point.  Are you developing an MS Access database front end, or coding in VB6?

Comment: Ms access is my back end ... i want to add this detail from vb6 coding .... thnks for ur reply bro... plz help me

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to skin such a cat.  One is to source your ComboBox data from a disconnected hierarchical Recordset created using the Data Shaping Service.

This example assumes a CSV file with a header row, but the same thing works with a Jet or other database table:

```
Option Explicit

Private rsShapedProducts As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub cboCategories_Click()
    With cboProducts
        .Clear
        With rsShapedProducts
            .MoveFirst
            .Find "[Category]='" & cboCategories.List(cboCategories.ListIndex) & "'"
            With ![Products].Value
                .MoveFirst
                Do Until .EOF
                    cboProducts.AddItem ![Product].Value
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
            End With
        End With
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cboProducts_Click()
    lblSelection.Caption = cboCategories.List(cboCategories.ListIndex) _
                         & " -> " _
                         & cboProducts.List(cboProducts.ListIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set rsShapedProducts = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rsShapedProducts
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "SHAPE {" _
            & "SELECT [Category], [Product] FROM [products.txt] " _
            & "ORDER BY [Category], [Product]" _
            & "} AS [Products] COMPUTE [Products] BY [Category]", _
              "Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
            & "Data Source='" & App.Path & "';Extended Properties='Text;Hdr=Yes'", _
              adOpenStatic, _
              adLockReadOnly, _
              adCmdText
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
        Do Until .EOF
            cboCategories.AddItem ![Category].Value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    Show
    cboCategories.ListIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    rsShapedProducts.Close
End Sub
```

Test data I used:

```
Category,Product
Fan,Ceiling Fan
Fan,Table Fan
Fan,Wall Fan
Lamp,Floor Lamp
Lamp,Table lamp
Lamp,Desk Lamp
Table,Coffee Table
Table,End Table
Table,Kitchen Table
Table,Dining Table
Table,Card Table
```

Comment: The code gives an error   ...... ' The Microsoft.jet database engine could not find the object 'products.txt', Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Comment: My table name is products

Comment: Surely you can make the changes needed to use your Connection and SQL matching your database?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function IsInCollection(ByVal Coll As Collection, CollKey As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim b As Variant
    b = Coll(CollKey)
    IsInCollection = True
errHandler:
    Err.Clear
    Exit Function
End Function

Public Sub FillCombo()
    Dim rs As Adodb.Recordset
    Dim Coll As New Collection
    Dim strNewValue As String
    Set rs = fillMyRs
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        strNewValue = rs.Fields("category").Value
        If IsInCollection(Coll, strNewValue) Then
            strNewValue = strNewValue & " - " & rs.Fields("product_name").Value
        Else
            Coll.Add strNewValue, strNewValue
        End If
        Combo1.AddItem strNewValue
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Brother i want to add category value to combo1 and then product_name value to combo2  where category is same see my table in question .... my table name is product  plz help me